# How to handle Optional ENUM in Query Parameter in C# Rest API - Invalid and null value and also hide specific value in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I am working on one Web API (.NET Framewrok) - where I wanted to use an ENUM in a query parameter.

I wanted to keep it as optional parameter, and if provided, the value is matched with a defined value then it's fine.  Otherwise it should take any default value which I will specify.

But the problem is  - I kept definition like this:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Application(UserType? user = null)
```

So by doing this -  it is optional parameter but whenever I don't pass anything or pass invalid value it always takes null and if I keep it as public like this:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Application(UserType? user = UserType.INVALID)
```

then it always takes INVALID (If value provided as invalid or null).

The things above are fine because of the default behavior.

But I want that whenever Invalid value is provided it should take INVALID and I want to hide this value from Swagger Drop down.  And if nothing is provided then it should be null.  But as far as I know, only one of the scenario can be possible.
**So if there is any trick to handle both scenarios then please suggest and also suggest how to hide the INVALID - ENUM value from the Swagger UI.**

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `HttpResponseMessage Application(UserType? user)`. Then the case of invalid enum value will be handled as a BadRequest, and passing nothing will be treated as null.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
But I have few conditions (on body parameter along with query parameter ) based on that I have to do certain operations and then I have to make  call to my db/systems.

Comment: On body parameter you don't have a problem as swagger doesn't provide default values. For the query params I can't think of any solution and maybe you need to rethink about your implementation.

Comment: Yes, last option is to change the way I wanted to implement my functionality.
But just for the information I would like to tell you the functionality that I have implement.
There is one field in body and this query parameter, if query param is null and field in body is equal to A (example) then I need to perform certain operation and if query param is invalid value (need to hide from swagger UI  - this INVALID (ENUM value)) and field in body is B then  I need to perform another operation.